# How to implement a Facebook like button without leaving iOS app?

Tags: ios7, ios6, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I was wondering how can I implement a Facebook "Like" and "Unlike" button right within my app without making the user leave the app. I know Apple has implemented this in their App Store app, so it is clearly possible. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Notice how you can press the like and unlike buttons and you remain in the App Store application. I would like to link these like buttons to my Facebook page.

Comment: Have you find any good solution for this yet? @cgossain.